# how to make a php crontab silent

Tags: linux, php, cron

I set up a crontab in Cpanel to run every min. It's working great but I don't want an e-mail every min. I have a second cron tab that runs every day. I would like the responce of this tab. Is there a way to tell the crontab to be silent or only e-mail on error?

I have:

```
    *    *  *   *   * php /home/public_html/folder/file.php 2>&1
```

The last bit `2>&1` I added because i thought it would make it silent.

From the Cpanel Docs:

> You can have cron send an email everytime it runs a command. If you do not want an email to be sent for an individual cron job you can redirect the command's output to /dev/null like this: mycommand >/dev/null 2>&1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `-q` it means "quiet" and thus doesn't generate output

```
*    *  *   *   * php -q /home/public_html/folder/file.php
```

also, ask yourself why you want to run it every minute, that's a little excessive.

Comment: It's a crontab that checks the status of buses in real time. The file is checking to see how many minutes the bus is away and if it's close alerts the user.

Comment: Also, `-q` did the trick.

Comment: If it needs to run once a minute, what's the problem with that?  Surely the developer knows why it needs to run so frequently...

Comment: @Tom generally cron may not be the right solution for things that need to run that often. But that's an opinion, and one that we enforce at work.

Comment: @xenoterracide what are some other options to check a database and sent out alerts on a realtime basis?

Comment: @bandnon 1 minute intervals aren't realtime anyways... but long running scripts that poll will do it, event driven programming might be good, when an alert is generated, send it.

Answer (score 1):

`2>&1` redirects the everything written to stderr to stdout

`>/dev/null` redirects stdout to /dev/null

cron will always email you anything sent to stdout or stderr unless redirected elsewhere.  Ideally, your PHP script should be rewritten to accept a --quiet flag that doesn't write a whole bunch of useless crap out to stdout, which you could then use in your cron job.

The lazy man's option is to put a [wrapper script](http://sysadvent.blogspot.com/2009/12/cron-practices.html) around your cron job that will stop it from emailing you unless your command exits non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

The correct setup would be

```
>/dev/null
```

This makes the standard output be ignored and only emails you if there is an error

Your current setup doesn't handle the standard output therefore you get an email every time it runs.

Comment: You're assuming that errors are being printed to stderr rather than stdout.  This is not a safe assumption.

Comment: I see. I also see that curl has --silient but can I curl an php script?

Comment: @BandonRandon, you can curl URLs like http/https if this was your question.

Comment: @l1x yes that was my question. That would make it run just like loading it in the browser correct?

Comment: @BandonRandon yes, like http://yourdoma.in/folder/file.php

Comment: Okay, so that's another route to go. The accept answer seemed to be a simple solution.